# Acton bar action menu - SearchView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I have a search view as an action item. Every thing is working fine except that I want to intercept the search executed event. At that time a new activity is started with search results. When that happens I want to collaps the search view in the previous activity. So when user comes back out of the search result activity, the action menu should be collapsed.

Comment: I think, the most easy way is to collapse in onPause method in your activity.

Comment: Thats what I though. But how do I get the reference to the action item in onPause().

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Used to put dark icons on light action bar

        //Create the search view
        final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search");

        menu.add(Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,1,"Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText.length() > 0) {
                    // Search

                } else {
                    // Do something when there's no input
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "dummy Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() { 
                         setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                     } 
                }, 2000);

                return false; }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

I think you can collapse `SearchView` in `onQueryTextSubmit` method, see above code